# Seg fault when using ctypes with Python and C++

Tags: c++, python, ctypes

I am trying to get up and running with using ctypes to call C++ libraries from Python 2.7 on a Linux machine. For the moment, I'm just trying toy examples. I read and was able to replicate the example given in this thread: [Calling C/C++ from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python). Note that the C++ class functions take no inputs.

I'm trying to extend this example as follows.

**foo.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
  Foo(string name);
  void bar(void);
private:
  string myName;
};
Foo::Foo(string name) {
  std::cout << "Entered constructor in C++" << std::endl;
  myName = name;
}
void Foo::bar(void) {
  std::cout << "Hello, this is " << myName << std::endl;
}

extern "C" {
  Foo* Foo_new(string name) {return new Foo(name);}
  void Foo_bar(Foo* foo) {foo->bar();}
}
```

The code compiles cleanly using `g++ -c -fPIC foo.cpp -o foo.o` and then `g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so -o libfoo.so foo.o`.

I then use the following wrapper,

**fooWrapper.py**

```
from ctypes import cdll, c_char_p
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libfoo.so')

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.obj = lib.Foo_new(c_char_p(name))
    def bar(self):
        lib.Foo_bar(self.obj)
```

Because I'm passing a string to the constructor, I'm under the impression that I need to cast it using `c_char_p`. Maybe this is wrong.

When I execute the code in Python 2.7, I get a segmentation fault,

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Feb 27 2012, 18:28:19) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import fooWrapper as f
>>> foo = f.Foo('somename')
Segmentation fault
```

So I never get into the C++ constructor function. I have the same problem whether or not I include the `self.name = name` line in the constructor method in the Python code.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: std::string is not a typedef to a pointer, it's a class. I'm not 100% sure, but I'd try changing your Foo to take a character pointer and see if it doesn't segment fault that way.  I'm not sure how you'd change it to maintain compatibility with std::string but I'm sure theres a way.

Comment: You are calling `Foo` constructor in `f.Foo('somename')` from python.shouldn't you do `f.bar` instead from your python code ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `extern "C"` you declare `Foo_new` to take a `std::string` argument, however for the code to be callable from Python you have to make it a true C function, which include receiving strings a character pointers. Especially as you actually tells the interpreter to convert your string to a character pointer (that's what the `c_char_p` call does).

Comment: Thanks, I appear to have fixed it. In my `extern "C"`, I now have `Foo* Foo_new(char* name) {return new Foo(name);}` with everything else the same. This works.