# ctypes/C++ segfault accessing member variables

Tags: c++, python, ctypes

I am no stranger to the python ctypes module, but this is my first attempt at combining C++, C and Python all in one code. My problem seems to be very similar to [Seg fault when using ctypes with Python and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142766/seg-fault-when-using-ctypes-with-python-and-c?lq=1), however I could not seem to solve the problem in the same way.

I have a simple C++ file called `Header.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
   public:
      int nbits;
      Foo(int nb){nbits = nb;}
      void bar(){ std::cout << nbits << std::endl; }
};

extern "C" {
   Foo *Foo_new(int nbits){ return new Foo(nbits); }
   void Foo_bar(Foo *foo){ foo->bar(); }
}
```

which I compile to a shared library using:

```
g++ -c Header.cpp -fPIC -o Header.o
g++ -shared -fPIC -o libHeader.so  Header.o
```

and a simple Python wrapper called `test.py`:

```
import ctypes as C
lib = C.CDLL('./libHeader.so')

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,nbits):
        self.nbits = C.c_int(nbits)
        self.obj = lib.Foo_new(self.nbits)

    def bar(self):
        lib.Foo_bar(self.obj)

def main():
    f = Foo(32)
    f.bar()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I would expect that when I call test.py, I should get the number 32 printed to screen. However, all I get is a segmentation fault. If I change the constructor to return the class instance on the stack (i.e. without the `new` call) and then pass around the object, the program performs as expected. Also, if I change the `bar` method in the `Foo` class such that it does not use the `nbits` member, the program does not seg fault.

I have an limited understanding of C++, but the fact that I can make this function as expected in C and in C++ but not in Python is a little confusing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**: Thanks to one of the comments below, the problem has been solved. In this case, an explicit declaration of both restype and argtypes for the C functions was required. i.e the following was added to the python code:

```
lib.Foo_new.restype  = C.c_void_p
lib.Foo_new.argtypes = [C.c_int32]
lib.Foo_bar.restype  = None
lib.Foo_bar.argtypes = [C.c_void_p]
```

Comment: Works for me. Also possible Erratum: I assume that you compiled Header.cpp with the -fPIC switch?

Comment: Works here, too. Please provide a gdb backtrace of the segfault.

Comment: Works for me too. You are passing around the pointer to Foo as C int, which might fail. Try to specify the function argtypes and restype, e.g. `lib.Foo_new.restype = C.c_void_p;lib.Foo_new.argtypes = [C.c_int32];lib.Foo_bar.restype = None;lib.Foo_bar.argtypes = [C.c_void_p]`

Comment: @cgohlke: Hit the nail on the head there, problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: Normally passing ints and pointers doesn't need the types declared, but it may be related to passing a c_int(32) to Foo_new instead of just a Python integer.

Comment: Any argument or return type other than C int should be declared. Otherwise stack or memory corruption can occur depending on platform and chance.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

```
extern "C"
{
    Foo *Foo_new(int nbits)
    {
        Foo *foo = new Foo(nbits);
        printf("Foo_new(%d) => foo=%p\n", nbits, foo);
        return foo;
    }
    void Foo_bar(Foo *foo)
    {
        printf("Foo_bar => foo=%p\n", foo);
        foo->bar();
    }
 }
```

to see if the values of `foo` match.

Also, you might want to look at Boost.Python to simplify creating Python bindings of C++ objects.

Comment: In this case the amount of code to be wrapped is very small, therefore I think using Boost.Python would be overkill and add unnecessary dependencies.